# TypeScript Map from another file outputs correct values, but I cannot use get()

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I am in the process of making a sprite map generator with TypeScript and am storing each of the sprites and their names in a Map. When I try to use this map in another file, I am able to get accurate output about its keys and values, but trying to get() with a proper key will always return undefined and checking its size will return 0.

```
// mapbuilder.ts
export class MapBuilder {
    tiles: Array<string>;
    code: Map<string, string>;
    sprites: SpriteSet;

    #files: Map<string, HTMLImageElement>;

    setBackground(background: string) {
        this.background = background;
    }

    load() {
        console.log(this.sprites.map); // Shows accurate information
        let m = this.sprites.map;
        console.log(m);  // Also shows the accurate information of the map
        console.log(m.keys()); // Shows me the correct keys, including "grass" 
        console.log(m.get("grass")); // Returns undefined

        ctx.fillStyle = this.background;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (let row = 0; row < this.tiles.length; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < this.tiles[0].length; col++) {
                const key = this.code.get(this.tiles[row].charAt(col))!;
                let spr: Sprite = Map.prototype.get.call(this.sprites.map, key);
                let src = spr.file; // Throws error

                // ... 
            }
        }
    }
}

// This map comes from another class, called SpriteSet. 

// ---

// Generation of this map is in another file ...
// spriteset.ts
export class Sprite {
    file: string;
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(file: string, x: number, y: number) {
        this.file = file;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

export class SpriteSet {
    map: Map<string, Sprite>;

    addToSpriteSet(path: string, arr: string[]) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = path;
        img.onload = (() => {
            for (let i = 0; i < img.width / 16; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < img.height / 16; j++) {
                    let spr = new Sprite(img.src, j * 16, i * 16);
                    this.map.set(arr[i * img.width / 16 + j], spr);
                }
            }
        })
        // Printing here outputs the correct information.
    }
}
```

Edit: Added all relevant files

I have been unable to find an answer to this question after about half an hour of searching, and have tried making the "map" variable both private and public, accessing it through getters, and using forEach loops to no success. How can I access the values of this map? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Map.prototype.get.call(m, "grass")`?  I suspect that something has overwritten the `get` method for that `Map`.  As it stands though, this code doesn't reproduce the problem, so we're not going to be able to debug it and help.  Can you provide a minimal example that _reproduces_ this problem?

Comment: Hello! I have added the appropriate files from my project. Please let me know if this works. Thank you!